I want to calculate a 1D Gaussian along multiple 1D planes and then take the average. How can I do this in Python?
I have a code that performs 2D Gaussian fitting within a specific area. I have a 4D variable where the fourth dimension represents time. I want to calculate a 1D Gaussian along multiple 1D planes and then take the average. How can I do this in Python?
The data used to fit 2D Gaussian it's in the next code


def compute_diffusivity(temperature,mask_heating,pt_coor,waiting_duration,heating_duration, resolution1,resolution2,delta_t,display=1):
    lNumberOfRepetitions = temperature.shape[3]
    temp_masquee = temperature*mask_heating   #(128, 128, 8, 200)
    weight = []
    dim,c,r = pt_coor    # dim = 3  , c = 86 , r = 68
   
    size_xy = np.array(temperature.shape)  #[128 128   8 200]
    height, width, depth, repetitions = temp_masquee.shape

    # compute the maximum crop size
    max_size = min(size_xy[0] - pt_coor[1], size_xy[1] - pt_coor[2], pt_coor[1],      pt_coor[2])-1

    print('maxsize',max_size)

    # make sure the crop size is even
    if max_size % 2 != 0:
        max_size -= 1

    y, x = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,temp_masquee.shape[1])[r-max_size:r+max_size], np.arange(0,temp_masquee.shape[0])[c-max_size:c+max_size]) # x (80, 80) y (80, 80)
    s = dim  

    print("temperature.shape[2]",temperature.shape[2])
    sigmax= []
    sigmay= []
    dyn = []
    #compute std without taking into account 0 values
    std_tempo=np.nanmean(np.where(temp_masquee[y,x,s,waiting_duration] == 0., np.nan, np.std(temp_masquee[y,x,s,10:waiting_duration],(2))))
    if display == 1:
        fig,axes =plt.subplots(2, 4, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [4,12,1,20],'height_ratios': [1,3] })
    err=[]
    end = waiting_duration+heating_duration +17
    if end >lNumberOfRepetitions-1:
        end = lNumberOfRepetitions-1
    for d in np.arange(waiting_duration + heating_duration+2, end, 1):
        z = np.squeeze(temp_masquee[y,x,s,d]) # zshape (80, 80)



 #second version
yData = z[z!=0.] #(211,)
xData1 = np.vstack((np.argwhere(z!=0)[:,0]+r-max_size, np.argwhere(z!=0)[:,1]+c-  max_size)) #(2, 211)


      


Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.
